# What causes furnaces to break in 16 to 20 years?

Tags: furnace

Why do furnaces need to be replaced in this regularly-occurring amount of time?(http://www.homeenergycenter.com/8furnace_signs.html)

Is there something about the physics of the high heat and components involved that makes this an absolute necessity? It's obviously very expensive and something to try to avoid if possible.

I've also seen some websites say around a 30-year lifetime for some furnaces. Which brands last the longest and do any last indefinitely?

Comment: Because the warranty expires

Comment: Can you provide any data to back up the claim that furnaces break in 15 to 18 years?  With proper maintenance and repairs, a furnace could technically last forever. However, as technology advances, furnaces get better and more efficient. These advancement mean that it might make sense to update the system from time to time.

Comment: Thermal fatigue and oxidation. Things Wear Out. Iron/Steel flakes, Stainless Steel ablates, Fire brick and ceramics spall and crack. Overfiring happens and your nice soapstone stove that could last 30 years splits.

Comment: It depends on the type of furnace. Gass forced air units usually last 30-40 years and I have found some much older. Heat pumps do have a much shorter life because of the components, electric forced air are in between. They all require regular maintenance or the life will be much shorter. It all depends on the type and little things like filter changes, lubrication of the fan motor. Even the area you live close to the coast the salt eats the cooling coils of a heat pump.

Comment: @Tester101 I can't remember exactly where I saw that 15-18 year range but a Google of "furnace lifetime" yields 16 to 20 as its first result (http://www.homeenergycenter.com/8furnace_signs.html). I've changed the question to be 16-20. I've seen very little out there that says that a furnace could technically last forever, but I certainly hope that's true with good maintenance.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan notice I said maintenance **and repair**.  Mechanical parts will fail over time, and need to be replaced

Comment: @Tester101 Ahhh, I should have also mentioned repair. But even so, I didn't see any source out there that said furnaces could last forever with maintenance and repair. Always seemed like furnaces died after 40 years max.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan a furnace can work until they stop making replacement parts, you get tired of fixing it, or you decide to get a newer model.

Answer (score -2):

its called planned obsolescence.  its the modern business strategy manufactures follow.  no longer is long life a selling point that means anything.  if a company can double its profits by selling you a furnace twice as often as it used to, they feel thats the best model of operation.

a furnace will only last as long as you wish to keep repairing it.